# What is "CHAD" in the context of Albion Online?

Tags: terminology, albion-online

I keep hearing people referring to "dungeon CHADs" in Albion Online. What are they talking about? Is this is an acronym for something?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just talking about Chads in general?

Comment: @Penguin I don't know. What is a Chad?

Comment: @TylerDurden https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/virgin-vs-chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chad (Full name: Chad Thundercock) basically means someone who is super good or super bad. It's extremely hard to explain because it literally means two opposites but is generally means at the very least noteworthy. Most of the time when Chad is used, it is someone who is amazing and someone who (idk how to say this) wettens. I don't play this game but in this context I assume the Dungeon Chads are either:

- Players who are really good at the dungeons
- Very good bosses (or whatever enemies are called) in the dungeons

Chad is one of those words that doesn't really have a definition, just everyone who knows what a Chad is knows Chad. Chad has no real meaning, and it can mean anything the user wants really, just most people know what a Chad is.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Albion this mostly refers to a popular YouTube video guide for Albion where the thumbnail says "Dungeon Chad" on it. The YouTuber is also in his own alliance named [CHADS]. It's just the Chad meme being used to describe a meta build for running dungeons.